# Call method with multiple parameter by performSelector ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

This is my method with two parameters: `imgArray` and `andDurationArray`.
I want to call this same method with same two parameters, in my `else` section, by `performSelector`. How can I call it? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
-(void) imageAnimationWithImage:(NSArray *) imgArray andDurationArray:(NSArray *) durationArr
{
    if (count == imgarray.count)
    {
        count = 0;
        [self imageAnimationWithImage:imgarray andDurationArray:durationArr];
    }
    else
    {
        emoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imgarray objectAtIndex:count]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(imageAnimationWithImage:andDurationArray:) withObject:imgarray withObject:durationArr afterDelay:[[durationArr objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue]];
        count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dispatch_after`. It's much easier:

```
double delay = [[durationArr objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self imageAnimationWithImage:imgarray andDurationArray:durationArr];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `NSInvocation`it suits better with multiple arguments, second pay attention that you are creating a method with a high risk of recursion

```
  NSInteger delay = [[durationArr objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue];
  SEL aSelector = @selector(imageAnimationWithImage:andDurationArray:);
  NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
  NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
  [invocation setTarget:self];
  [invocation setSelector:aSelector];
  [invocation setArgument:&imgarray atIndex:2];
  [invocation setArgument:&durationArr atIndex:3];

  [invocation performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand it, except 3 lines. Can you please explain these to me?
First one: `[invocation setArgument:&imgarray atIndex:2];`
Why did you set the index at 2?
Second one: ` [invocation setArgument:&durationArr atIndex:3];`
Why did you set the index at 3?
Third one: [invocation performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:delay];
Where did the invoke came from?

Comment: Indices 0 and 1 indicate the hidden arguments self and _cmd, respectively; you should set these values directly with the target and selector properties.  The "invoke" is the methods that starts the invocation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSInvocation/setArgument:atIndex:

Comment: Great. Got it. But using `dispatch_after` is more easier, I think. Thanks for introducing some thing new to me.

Comment: You are welcome, NSInvocation is a really powerful class, but it can be difficult, dispatch_after is a lot easier but pay attention to reference cicles

Comment: You need to make sure to do `[invocation retainArguments];` since you are invoking it asynchronously, or else bad things will happen.

Answer (score 2):

The method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` will only work with 0 or 1 parameters. You can package your parameters in a dictionary and pass that, or use dispatch_after, which inherits the enclosing scope, and so doesn't need parameters.

Comment: Yes, I am going to use `dispatch_after`. But thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: I created a category of NSObject that adds a method `performBlock:afterDelay:`. (Internally it uses dispatch_after.) I add that to all my projects and then just use that. It's easier to remember (and to read) than the rather elaborate syntax of dispatch_after.